# Traversing through a table with javascript to compare with row values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my table looks like this.

```
<body>
<table class="tblTest">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>wer</label></td>
        <td>
            <label>ur4</label></td>
        <td>
            <label>ksdj</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>eiejr</label></td>
        <td>
            <label>ur4</label></td>
        <td>
            <label>yutu56</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" /></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" /></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>jweee</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>male</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>ur4</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>ssssss</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>male</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>ur4s</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" /></td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Male
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="cars" style="width: 128px">
                <option selected="selected" value="Select">Select</option>
                <option value="saab">BMW</option>
                <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table> <br />
<button type="button" onclick="function1()">Submit</button>
```

I want a Java script/jQuery which will check the two labels and if there is a mismatch then it will make the Text Box Red and if not then green. I can't use getElementById for the labels only I have to traverse through it and get the td index and do the task. I Don't know how to get prev and closest elements.  Please help me with this.
The function which I'm trying is

```
function function1() {
        var inputcontrols = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputcontrols.length; ++i)
        {
            var element = inputcontrols[i];
            //element.style.background = "#90EE90"; by default making it green
            var ind = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').text();
            alert(ind);
        }
```

Trying to get the td text in "ind", but its returning empty.

Comment: Which two label you want to check ?Where is the text  box?

Comment: @user2181397 one row is "wer" and "eiejr", the second one is "ur4" and "ur4". Just use the code in any editor and you can see the table view.

Comment: @Soviut please see the function, I have updated it. I can't get the td text in 'ind'.

Comment: You're using a very strange mixture of raw javascript and jQuery. If you're already using jQuery it would be much easier to use its selectors and traversal functions instead of mixing the two.

Comment: Your code says `var ind` but the alert says `alert(index)`. Which one is it?

Comment: Can you share it with jQuery if you have a solution for this. I don't know much about jQuery. I have changed it and it should use ind.Thanks

Comment: Also, are you trying to compare the two text fields, or are you comparing the text fields to their respective values in the previous row?

Comment: I'm not going to do your work for you. I'll explain a few of the issues you seem to be facing, but I'm not going to just give you code to copy and paste.

Comment: It has to compare 0,0 with 1,0 and 0,1 with 1,1. The 0 and 1 are row column .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get all the inputs, and use the `each` loop to iterate these. And by using the index to get the appropriate label texts.

The reason `text()` did not work for you, is because you are trying to get the text from the `td` element. This is empty, because it only contains a HTMLElement `label`. Look at the jQuery specs to see the difference between [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
function function1() {
    $('table').each(function(n, table) {
      $(table).find('tr').each(function(n, tr) {
        tr = $(tr);
        var td = undefined;
        var c = 0;
        tr.find('input,select').each(function(i, input) {
            if(!td || !td.is($(input).closest('td'))) {
              td = $(input).closest('td');
              c++;
            }
            var lbl1 = $(tr.prev().prev().find('td')[c]).find('label').text();
            var lbl2 = $(tr.prev().find('td')[c]).find('label').text();

            if(lbl1 === lbl2) {
                $(input).css('backgroundColor', 'green');
            } else {
                $(input).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
            }

        });
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks it is working fine but I can't use the table id because it will generate automatically and I don't know the id. so i have to find the text box index and from that index i have to get the corresponding  td values and compare.

Comment: Hello @PierreDuc i need little more help in this thing. I have added another 3 rows but its working for only the first 3 rows. Please see the table design now. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the edit. But still its no working for the below rows. Can you check again. Its changing the color for the first 3 text boxes.

Comment: I've modified one little thing. But that could not have been the problem. I made a plnkr, and it works there: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5GBO4ZvchFAW0cu9zx5v)

Comment: I've checked it in plnkr there its making all the below text boxes green even though the lbls are different.

Comment: I'm sorry indeed. I've made a new [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jzEFxtlnGC1R3C7v5q0I?p=info) , and updated my answer

Comment: Already fixed that, but Thanks a lot for your help @PierreDuc.

Comment: Hi @PierreDuc , I have added a drop down and two radio buttons in the tr , but its not working for the drop down and only one radio button is changing color according to the text. Can you please check the table and give any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve with all this ;). But I've changed my answer once again and updated this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8U2mexTDwwWtswObyzVM?p=preview). I've added a `select` in the search selector. The radio boxes won't visibly change their `background-color`, but the value does get set. Just that this css does not work on radio buttons

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I see is that you're using `$(this)` which is what how you chain the function scope in jQuery. For example:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    // 'this' scopes to the current 'a' element inside the 'each' loop
    $(this).css('color', '#FF0000');
});
```

Since you've already found your input controls and stored them in `var element` you need to pass that element into jQuery so it knows what you're looking for.

```
var element = inputcontrols[i];
$(element).closest('td').prev('td').text();
```

Next, if you're trying to compare the text field to the previous label you need to fix your traversal steps to be:

- From the text field
- Find its parent `tr` not `td` (go up to the row)
- Find its the previous `tr` (go back a row)
- Find its child `label` (drill down into the previous row)
- Get the text from the label

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am new to javascript and jQuery so I am not able to do the traversing properly. only know how to do it by id name. Anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you only have two table rows, you can try this-

```
function function1() {
    var inputs = $('.tblTest input');
    var tr1 = $('.tblTest tr:nth(0)');
    var tr2 = $('.tblTest tr:nth(1)');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i)
    {
        var element = inputcontrols[i];
        if(tr1.find('td:nth('+ i +') label').html().trim() == tr2.find('td:nth('+ i +') label').html().trim()) {
            element.style.background = "green";
        }
        else {
            element.style.background = "red";
        }
    }
}
```